# Liquid water "evaporation" or diffusion mass transfer?

Tags: evaporation

Is the disappearance of liquid rain water at < 100 deg C (< 212 deg F) @ atmospheric pressure after it stops raining and the sun comes out an example of evaporation and/or diffusion mass transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Both water evaporates from the liquid, but then diffuses from the vicinity of the liquid into the bulk of the atmosphere.